# Trying to install Yt-Dlp module but having problems with Brotli installation step

Tags: python, module, pip

I'm trying to install the Yt-Dlp module for Python 3.11 but for some reason I get this error

```bash
Building wheels for collected packages: brotli
  Building wheel for brotli (setup.py) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × python setup.py bdist_wheel did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [20 lines of output]
      C:\Users\igor\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\dist.py:771: UserWarning: Usage of dash-separated 'build-base' will not be supported in future versions. Please use the underscore name 'build_base' instead
        warnings.warn(
      running bdist_wheel
      running build
      running build_py
      creating bin
      creating bin\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311
      copying python\brotli.py -> bin\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311
      running build_ext
      building '_brotli' extension
      creating bin\temp.win-amd64-cpython-311
      creating bin\temp.win-amd64-cpython-311\Release
      creating bin\temp.win-amd64-cpython-311\Release\c
      creating bin\temp.win-amd64-cpython-311\Release\c\common
      creating bin\temp.win-amd64-cpython-311\Release\c\dec
      creating bin\temp.win-amd64-cpython-311\Release\c\enc
      "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.34.31933\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe" /c /nologo /O2 /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -Ic/include -IC:\Users\igor\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\include -IC:\Users\igor\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Include "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.34.31933\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\VC\Auxiliary\VS\include" /Tcc/common/constants.c /Fobin\temp.win-amd64-cpython-311\Release\c/common/constants.obj
      constants.c
      C:\Users\igor\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-cplthpdp\brotli_bec0f5da12d0434ea2253cdadf0efb64\c\common\./platform.h(26): fatal error C1083: NÆo ‚ poss¡vel abrir arquivo incluir: 'string.h': No such file or directory
      error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2022\\BuildTools\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.34.31933\\bin\\HostX86\\x64\\cl.exe' failed with exit code 2
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for brotli
  Running setup.py clean for brotli
Failed to build brotli
Installing collected packages: brotli, websockets, yt-dlp
  Running setup.py install for brotli ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × Running setup.py install for brotli did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [22 lines of output]
      C:\Users\igor\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\dist.py:771: UserWarning: Usage of dash-separated 'build-base' will not be supported in future versions. Please use the underscore name 'build_base' instead
        warnings.warn(
      running install
      C:\Users\igor\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\install.py:34: SetuptoolsDeprecationWarning: setup.py install is deprecated. Use build and pip and other standards-based tools.
        warnings.warn(
      running build
      running build_py
      creating bin
      creating bin\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311
      copying python\brotli.py -> bin\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311
      running build_ext
      building '_brotli' extension
      creating bin\temp.win-amd64-cpython-311
      creating bin\temp.win-amd64-cpython-311\Release
      creating bin\temp.win-amd64-cpython-311\Release\c
      creating bin\temp.win-amd64-cpython-311\Release\c\common
      creating bin\temp.win-amd64-cpython-311\Release\c\dec
      creating bin\temp.win-amd64-cpython-311\Release\c\enc
      "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.34.31933\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe" /c /nologo /O2 /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -Ic/include -IC:\Users\igor\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\include -IC:\Users\igor\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Include "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.34.31933\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\VC\Auxiliary\VS\include" /Tcc/common/constants.c /Fobin\temp.win-amd64-cpython-311\Release\c/common/constants.obj
      constants.c
      C:\Users\igor\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-cplthpdp\brotli_bec0f5da12d0434ea2253cdadf0efb64\c\common\./platform.h(26): fatal error C1083: NÆo ‚ poss¡vel abrir arquivo incluir: 'string.h': No such file or directory
      error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2022\\BuildTools\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.34.31933\\bin\\HostX86\\x64\\cl.exe' failed with exit code 2
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: legacy-install-failure
```

I have already tried uninstalling and reinstalling the C++ Build Tools, resetting the PC, installing the Brotli package by itself but it still gives me this error, and not only I have no idea why, I cannot even comprehend error message. Can anyone help me?